# Scrape key check failed. Please try again

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, themes

I am not able to save the function.php file. I am getting one error

> Scrape key check failed. Please try again.

I have disabled all the plugins even removed all the codes from the function.php file and tried to save but still got the same error.

I am able to save the CSS and other files but not function.php

I am using the latest WordPress. Any idea what is the issue?

Comment: I searched for that error message on Google and found [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-update-php-files-shows-scrape-key-check-failed-please-try-again/#post-15106163), which might help..

Comment: @SallyCJ, I have checked that I have cleared the cache but I haven't found the Performance>general settings option

Comment: @SallyCJ, I have checked in Setting->General setting but there is no option called Fragment Cache

Comment: No offence ✌, but actually, I was only giving you an idea, which is, "search for that error message on Google" (because that isn't an error in WordPress core).. so try that and check all the relevant links. If none helps, then try posting a question on the plugin's support forums. But for now, you could try updating the file via FTP and not the file editor in WordPress admin.